# Is there an eloquent way of qualitatively explaining why the time coordinate of an event is shifted proportionally to its spatial coordinates?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, inertial-frames, observers

We know that time must shift alongside space because $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx'}{dt'}$ when $\frac{dx}{dt} = c$. This just means that the speed of light is invariant in all reference frames (light propagates at the same rate of space per time in all inertial reference frames). However, it is much more difficult to fundamentally understand why entities that do not propagate at $c$ (such as events that are separated from the origin by more space than can be traversed by light in the time between them) are shifted in time proportionally to their spatial coordinate relative to the observer, just as their spatial coordinates shift more as more time passes (dx'/dt /= 0) (spatial coordinates shift proportionally to time ($x'=\gamma(x-vt)$, and so dx'/dt /= 0) between inertial reference frames. Is there an eloquent and simple way of explaining why the time coordinate shifts more from the same coordinate in another reference frame as spatial coordinates increase (relative to the origin) as shown by the Lorentz transformation equation $t'=\gamma(t-\frac{vx}{c^2})$, and thus why t' is dependent on x (specifically, when they are not along a "light cone" relative to the origin?)? For example, events that are colocated in one reference frame are not in another because space shifts more over time. Why would events that are simultaneous in one frame occur at different points of time in another as time shift with respect to space? Is there a simple, eloquent, and qualitative way of explaining why events are shifted in time more over space using just some basic, intuitive fundamental properties of our universe? Can (dt'/dx /= 0) be shown without the invariance of C? It would be especially helpful if this explanation helps build intuition.

Essentially, why does time shift as a function of space just as space shifts as a function of time (Especially for events and entities that are not traveling at C)?

A major part of my issue is that in most Lorentz Transformation derivations, the person doing the derivation starts with saying that x' is a function of x, v, and t (x'=f(x,v,t)), and t' is a function of x, v, and t as well (t'=f(x,v,t)). They also state that these equations will be linear (which makes sense, as space is homogenous, so the derivative of a coordinate in one frame with respect to a coordinate in another cannot be dependent on x, as the difference is a law of physics that cannot depend on location). My issue was that there is generally no reason given for why t' should  be dependent on x (dt'/dx /= 0). So, please explain to me why t' should change with respect to x with just some intuitive axioms or fundamentals of our universe such as homogeneity of space (dx'/dx is equal to a nonzero constant). Is this possible to show without the invariance of c?

Comment: What would qualify to you as "eloquent"? There are many simple thought experiments that show why you have to have this term; most textbooks use one of these thought experiments to introduce it. However, there's no way to get this term from Galilean intuition, like the $-vt$ term, because it isn't present in Galilean physics at all.

Comment: What I mean by eloquent is relatively simple to understand and good for building intuition. I suppose you are right about your point about not being able to get this from Galilean intuition. I am looking for a simple way to develop and intuition of the (-vt/c^2) term for entities that are not traveling at C away from and observer. My issue is that most thought experiments focus only on events connected by C being shifted (which is valid)  but it is more difficult to intuitively understand why, say, an event simultaneous with the origin on one reference frame is shifted by the factor (-vt/c^2).

Comment: Have you seen the [train thought experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity#Einstein's_train)? (This is the most common one you find in standard books.)

Comment: This is why I am looking for an explanation for this factor on an intuitive level (hopefully in a way similar to Galilean relativity (although obviously different from it on a fundamental level)) specifically and especially for events that are not connected by C (i.e. events have spacelike separation (separated by more space than can be traversed by light)).

Comment: Yes, I have seen the train thought experiment, but it relies entirely on light signals, which is obviously a large part of special relativity, but it does little to show why this applies to events separated by more distance than C (i.e.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the train thought experiment. However, my issue with it is that it relies entirely upon light signals. While it is a large part of special relativity, it does little to explain why events that are separated by more distance than C (i.e. <300,000,000 m after 1 sec) shift by the factor (-vx/c^2). I wish to better understand why events shift by this factor, specifically, events that are separated by a different amount (ratio) of spacetime than C.

Comment: So, essentially, I am looking for an explanation of the -(vx/c^2) in the lorentz transformation in a way that explains why it applies to all entities (not just those that are exactly C apart (i.e. not 3*10^8 meters and 1 second apart) from each other) and that builds intuition.

Answer (score 3):

I ll take $(c=1)$ from now on.

I am not sure this is the explanation that you are looking for, but I 'll give it a try.

So for a moment let us forget about the $(x,t)$ coordinate system and focus on the normal cartesian coordinate system (i.e $(x,y)$).

Let us choose a point such that $P(x_p, y_p)$. Let us set another coordinate $(x',y')$ system such that it's rotated with $\theta$ degree with respect to the x-axis. If we wanted to write the point P in terms of $(x',y')$ we need to apply a coordinate transformation, which has a form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} \tag{1}$$

From here as you can see the length of the line element ($ds$) does not change under this transformation

$$ds^2 = dx^2+dy^2 = dx'^2+dy'^2$$

Now let us think of the SR case. In the SR the line element is defined such that

$$ds^2 = -dt^2+dx^2 = -dt'^2+dx'^2$$ (Which as you know comes from the fact that speed of light must be equal to the every inertial observer)

At this point we can naturally think a way to obtain coordinate transformation from $(x,t)$ to $(x',t')$.

Remember that $\cosh^2w - \sinh^2w =1$. Let me write this coordinate transformation directly

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\
t'
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(w) & -\sinh(w)\\
-\sinh(w) & \cosh(w)\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
t
\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}$$

This implies that $$x' = x\cosh(w) - t\sinh(w)\\t' = -x\sinh(w) + t\cosh(w)$$

By using (2) you can write that

$$ds^2 = -t^2+x^2 = -t'^2 + x'^2 \tag{3}$$

When you set $x=vt$ for $x'=0$ (and by using $\sinh(w) = \sqrt{\cosh^2(w)-1}$), you will see that $\cosh(w) = \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$ and
$\sinh(w) = v\gamma$

Note: Here $w$ is not an usual angle. Its an hyperbolic angle and called rapidity

> Essentially, why does time shift as a function of space just as space shifts as a function of time?

The simple answer is to preserve the $ds$ term invariant under the coordinate transformation (i.e equation 3) which is a crucial point in SR. This coordinate transformation (2) is similar to the one which I did for equation (1). So the $vx$ term comes naturally,  without it the transformations do not make sense.

Edit :

So as I said we need a transformation from $(x',t')$ to $(x,t)$ or vice versa. So assume a linear form of transformation such that

$$x' = ax + bt$$
$$t' = cx + dt$$

When you impose certain conditions such that

(i) $x = vt$ for $x' = 0$

(ii) $x' = -vt'$ for $x = 0$

(iii) $x = ct$ and $x'=ct'$ (Invariance of the speed of light)

You ll find that $a = \gamma$, $b = -v\gamma$ etc.

I am not sure how the $\cosh(w)$ and $\sinh(w)$ terms are derived but It's not hard to guess.

Again take the form of equations,

$$x' = ax + bt$$
$$t' = cx + dt$$

Square them

$$x'^2 = a^2x^2 + 2axbt + b^2t^2$$
$$t'^2 = c^2x^2 + 2cxdt + d^2t^2$$

So we know that,

$x'^2 - t'^2 = x^2-t^2$

This implies

$$[a^2x^2 + 2axbt + b^2t^2] - [c^2x^2 + 2cxdt + d^2t^2] = x^2 - t^2$$

so we have $a^2-c^2 = 1$ , $ab = cd$ and $b^2 - d^2 = 1$

We also know that $\cosh^2(w) - \sinh^2(w) = 1$ as you can see there's a similarity between these equations so we can set

$a = b = \cosh(w)$ and $c = d = \sinh(w)$ to satisfy the equations.

It may not seem certain, which is not, but you can see that the form must be somehow related to the $\cosh(w)$ and $\sinh(w)$.

Comment: Yes, this is the type of answer I was looking for. I was looking for an answer as to why the -(vx)/c^w factor exists and why it applies to entities that do not move at C from the origin in a well-written (i.e. somewhat easy to understand) way. Your answer accomplishes this. Thank you!

Comment: How does the invariance of C imply that the sine in the bottom right corner of the rotation matrix becomes negative? Why is this all that it implies in terms of this matrix? Essentially, would you please elaborate on how using spacetime as a coordinate system and how using the invariance of C as an axiom changes the rotation matrix/function to create the 'new' matrix shown in figure 2 above that describes spacetime?

Comment: @Sciencemaster Its not a rotation matrix as what we generally do in cartesian coordinate. Invarience of C determines the metric of the spacetime. I recently answered a question about it. Here is the link. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/540138/why-is-a-spacetime-interval-defined-as-delta-s2-eta-mu-nu-delta-x/540149#540149

Comment: @Sciencemaster I edited my post a bit. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for writing the edits. At first glance they seem to be intuitive. but there are some things that I noticed and would like some clarification on. First of all, in the original post you showed how we can derive the cosh and sinh using x^2-t^2 and so on and so forth. However, as t^2-x^2 and so forth is also a valid equation that instead applies to the time coordinate of events (rather than applying to the space coordinate of events like your first equation). Is your sinh and cosh derivation still valid for t^2-x^2 and so forth?

Comment: In addition, your edit doesn't quite make sense in how it shows that a=c=cosh. It states that a^2-b^2=1 just as cosh^2-sinh^2=1. However, this does not imply that a=cosh. 2 numbers that subtract to 1 are not in inherently equal (i.e. 3-2=1 just as 5-4=1). Perhaps I have misunderstood your reasoning or something of the like. Would you please put some further clarification into your answer? Despite this, your initial answer makes some intuitive sense. For example, upon further research, it seems that your cosh and sinh matrix for SR is just a mix of the clockwise and counterclockwise rotations.

Comment: @Sciencemaster "Is your sinh and cosh derivation still valid for t^2-x^2 and so forth? " I guess so. As I said  I am not sure how can we derive them I just made a some sort of guess. But since the metric changes from (-1,1,1,1) to (1,-1,-1,-1) I guess the derivation is still valid. "i.e. 3-2=1 just as 5-4=1." you are forgetting that ab=cd

Comment: I don't see how ab=cd shows that sinh-cosh=1 and a-c=2 shows that a=b=cosh and c=d=sinh. In addition, your original sin-cos rotational transformation "derivation" of Lorentz transformation seems to be ill-fitting with the Lorentz factor (gamma) and its "stretching" effect, although this point may be my classical intuition from everyday life getting in the way. Also is there an external source that this idea came from, or did you come up with it? If it was from another source, I would really like to see it, so that I can learn more about and dig deeper into this explanation.

Comment: I learned from Susskinds Relativity Lectures. If you want to learn more about these transitions there are plenty of books and online sources. Or you can ask a seperate question

Comment: Alright, that you so much! I'll definitely look at some of those other resources. Looking through this again, what does the dollar sign mean in the equation x'^2-t^2=x^2-t^2? Edit: the dollar sign won't show up in the comments as it just italicized my text, so I can't replicate it in the equation here.

Comment: @Sciencemaster that is just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Let's say an alarm clock going off is an event.

That event shifts in space when the alarm clock is moved in space.

If the moving of the clock does not cause time dilation of the clock, then the event of the clock going off does not shift in time, when the clock is shifted in space.

Those observers that observe the clock to become more time dilated, or less time dilated, when it is being moved, agree that doubling the time that the clock is being moved doubles the amount that the event gets shifted in time because of it being shifted in space.

And doubling the time that the clock is being moved also doubles the amount that the clock/event is shifted in space.

I think I should explain what clock being moved means. Well, think about an alarm clock at the rear of a long spaceship. An astronaut slowly carries the clock to the front of the spaceship. That is what clock being moved means here. A slow change of x-coordinate in the coordinate system attached to the spaceship. An astronaut carrying the clock very slowly causes a very small amount of time dilation in the spaceship frame, but has large effect on the clock in some other frames.

Comment: I don't think that this answer properly addresses my question. It does not explain the relativity of simultaneity or anything similar. It just restates time dilation, but does not explain why motion inherently changes time. Also, doubling speed does not inherently double time. In fact, time is doubled ( γ=2) when v=.86c.

Comment: @Sciencemaster The temporary time dilation of the alarm clock caused the alarm clock to shift in the time-dimension. Or it caused some change of simultaneity. Rest of the answer I do not understand anymore.

Comment: Alright, it is related. It does show that t'=/t. Thanks for your time and effort. I appreciate it.