# Why is a spacetime interval defined as $(\Delta s)^2$ = $\eta_{\mu\nu}\Delta x^{\mu} \Delta x^{\nu}$?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

I'm currently studying SR and GR and I noticed that all the books introduce spacetime interval without any motivation as $$(\Delta s)^2 = -c^2 (\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2$$ and than motivate that expression defining the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$.

Is there a physical reason why the metric of spacetime is the Minkowski metric?

Comment: I very much doubt that "all the books" do not motivate this quantity at all (e.g. by showing it is the interval preserved by Lorentz transformations).

Comment: You can easily show that this interval is invariant under lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple explanation**: Its the only type of metric that *conserves* the speed of light.

**Mathematical explanation**: Let us assume an inertial observer, $O$, measures the speed of light as $dx/dt = c$. Let us assume another inertial observer, $O'$, measuring the speed of light in his coordinates, $dx'/dt' = c$.

Naturally at this point one can ask, *What is the connection between $(t,x)$ and $(t',x')$ ?*

The crucial point is to keep $c$ a constant while doing this transformation. Calculations show that Galilean transformation does not satisfy this condition since $c$ varies.

Let us take $dx/dt = c$ and write in the form of $dx^2 - c^2dt^2=0$.

(PS: We need to square because light can move in either poisitive or in negative direction. Such that the equations should both satisfy for $dx/dt = c$ and $dx/dt = -c$. For this reason we should square both sides)

Similarly by using $dx'/dt' = c$,  we can write $dx'^2 - c^2dt'^2=0$

This implies that $$dx^2 - c^2dt^2=dx'^2 - c^2dt'^2$$

This transformation is the one that conserves the speed of light and that's what we're looking for.

In general we write this as $$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2$$

And later on, you can also show that

$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 = -c^2dt'^2 + dx'^2$

Comment: I think you need to say _why_ you are squaring, otherwise your argument applies without squaring anything and gives the wrong answer.

Comment: @m4r35n357 I edited my post

Comment: that deals with my comment, thanks!